# Is there a Chrome/Firefox extension to replace 'machine-unreadable' emails with human-readable ones?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser-addons

On mailing lists and a lot of other sites across the internet, it's turning into almost common courtesy to replace

```
some.email@some.domain.ext
```

with

```
some (dot) email (at) some (dot) domain (dot) ext
```

Does there exist an extension that will take the above and turn it into something more ... not annoying?

Ideally, such a script should also be able to handle the following:

```
some(dot)email(at)some(dot)domain(dot)ext
some(dot) email  (at) some  (dot) domain  (dot)  ext
...etc...
```

Comment: Have you looked? Because thats exactly what I would have to do to locate an extension/plug-in that did this.  You don't indicate what would not be annoying might be helpful to indicate what form you expect it to be transformed into.

Comment: The reason that people do this is to make it more difficult for bot scripts to farm email addresses. So while it is possible that someone has written a script/plugin/extension to do it, that script/plugin/extension would be contrary to the initial intent.

Comment: @EBGreen What? How does my user-agent reformatting the displayed representation make it easier for a bot script crawling the server to retrieve the email address? Or are you suggesting that the trivial deobfuscation involved is something no spam crawler author will have thought of doing before now?

Comment: As long as the mangled email address appears in that form in the html source, it is not too difficult to write a firefox extension to that end (including clickable mailto links). So easy that I assume one should be findable at the mozilla addon pages.

Comment: @Ramhound I have looked, but I didn't have the words to search for specifically.  I then looked for a general 'regex replace' extension on Chrome's webstore, but only found 'regex search'-type stuff (which is all fine and dandy, but not useful for this).  I included Firefox in the question not because I use it, but because I know it's the other popular browser where this Q might apply. I did find an [offline tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/regx/ljalefclkclbejlnejeagbpebmheejml/related?hl=en-US), but it doesn't interact with a displayed page as near as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a userscript that does what you're looking for. It's called [de-cr@pify.email](https://userscripts.org/scripts/show/23362). It appears to work for some obfuscated emails, but not all of the ones I've tried. You can install it on Firefox with an addon like [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) or [Scriptish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/scriptish/). It does successfully work on the email you provided (but not on this page because it ignores text in code tags): http://pastebin.com/qw0ksbDj

It keeps the text of the email the same, but wraps the text with a link to the actual email.

Comment: Excellent! A note to Chrome users: there is a userscript implementation extension available on [the Chrome webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo/related?hl=en).